# How to change default colors in materializecss?

Tags: asp.net, materialize

I just added materializecss to my ASP.NET MVC project, but I can't seem to change the default color scheme. [Referring to here](https://materializecss.com/color.html), I need to change the default color scheme from green to blue.

I added this to my '_project_variables.scss' file, but it doesn't work:

```
$primary-color: color("materialize-blue", "lighten-2") !default;
```

Is there another step that is not outlined on their website? What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to do this.

1) Edit [_variables.scss](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/components/_variables.scss) directly

Change the color values on lines 37 & 41 for primary and secondary (currently teal and pink).

2) Override with  `_custom-variables.scss`

In [materialize.scss](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/materialize.scss), add a link to your own custom scss file BEFORE `_variables.scss`:

```
// Variables;
@import "../custom-components/custom-variables";
@import "components/variables";
```